# add <div> to end of post in the loop with plugin

Tags: posts, loop, filters

I'm looking to add a `<div>` with some more html content to the bottom of specific posts in the loop. The `the_post` action can be used to add the `<div>` to the beginning of the post in the loop, but I'm hoping to add it to the end.

EDIT
The closest things I've been able to do is to add a classname to the desired post in the loop using `post_class`. Then I used `jQuery(.classname).append('<div>custom content</div>)` to add the custom content. The problem is, mixing jQuery and php in this manner seems to be less than optimal because I want to pass php info to the custom content...

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want a filter on [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content).

```
function add_content_wpse_97277($content) {
  global $post;
  if ($post->ID == 123) {
    $content .= 'additional content';
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','add_content_wpse_97277');
```

I don't know what conditions you need though. You did not explain that in the question. The above should match a post with an `ID` of "123".

For index pages you may need to add the same callback to the `the_excerpt` hook. You can control where the function adds content with [template tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) like `is_home` or `is_single`.

Honestly, this is how you should be adding your content both above and below the post. Echoing content from an action like `the_post` *can* work but is also a good way to get yourself in trouble. In this case I'd say it is particularly dangerous. `the_post` runs inside `setup_postdata` which does frequently run inside a loop that echoes content immediately, but if that function-- `setup_postdata`-- runs inside a Loop that doesn't echo immediately, for example to build a string, your markup will make a mess. There is also `loop_start` and `loop_end` but I don't think those are what you want.

Having seen your question and your comments and considered them, I have to say that your basic approach is wrong. You should be using the `the_content` and the `the_excerpt`, and/or possibly the `get_the_excerpt` filter as well.

> Unfortunately filtering the content/excerpt doesn't do what I need it
>   to do. There are often divs or footers added to a post (in the loop)
>   below the excerpt/content. That means filtering the content/excerpt
>   would not make my content appear at the bottom of the post in the
>   loop. Thanks though, your help is appreciated!
>
> quoted from a comment below

I doubt there is a reliable way to do what you want. The only filter you have to work with that I can see is `the_post`. You could use that to insert *between* posts by tracking which post of the Loop you are on and inserting content conditionally. That is:

1. If post number 0, then insert the begin `<div>`
2. If post number 1, then insert `</div>` and `<div>`
3. ...
4. If last post, then insert `</div>`

But again, you are ***going to make a mess `echo`ing content from the `the_post` filter*** when `setup_postdata` is used in a context that does not `echo` content immediately-- for example, in a context where a string is being built and returned.

Comment: Sorry but as far as I can tell that doesn't add a <div> to the loop. This adds content to the body of post 123's content. I'm looking to add a div below post 123 in the loop, not on post 123's single page. Sorry if that wasn't clear and thanks for the response!

Comment: This filter is not specific to the single post display unless your theme is intentionally written that way. There is a pretty fine distinction between "appended to the post body" and "after the post in the Loop". The answer is going is going to depend on your Loop and may require editing that Loop. There is no hook that I can think of that does what it now sounds like you want. Please edit your question to include the Loop code.

Comment: It's for a plugin, so I won't be able to edit the loop code... unless there's a way to do that that I don't know.

Comment: @bob_hardy, see the edit

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately filtering the content/excerpt doesn't do what I need it to do. There are often divs or footers added to a post (in the loop) below the excerpt/content. That means filtering the content/excerpt would not make my content appear at the bottom of the post in the loop. Thanks though, your help is appreciated!